# Closest to a square

Tags: code-golf, number

## The task

Given a positive integer `c`, output two **integers** `a` and `b` where `a * b = c` and each `a` and `b` is closest to `sqrt(c)` while still being integers.

## Test cases

```
Input: 136
Output: 17 8
```

```
Input: 144
Output: 12 12
```

```
Input: 72
Output: 9 8
```

```
Input: 41
Output: 41 1
```

```
Input: 189
Output: 21 9
```

## Rules

1. `a`, `b` and `c` are all positive integers
2. You may give `a` and `b` in any order, so for the first case an output of `8 17` is also correct
3. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest byte count wins!

Comment: Please notify me if this is a duplicate...

Comment: If the input integer is square may we output a single integer or must we repeat it?

Comment: @JonathanAllan it is up to you, although I would assume it's easier to repeat it.

Comment: This is [OIES A033676](https://oeis.org/A033676) (lower number) and [A033677](https://oeis.org/A033677) (higher number)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

Given an input \$ c \$, it outputs \$ a \$ and \$ b \$ as a list in increasing order. If \$ c \$ is a square, it outputs a single integer (which according to the OP is allowed).

```
ÑÅs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MTDrcX//xsamwEA)

### Explanation

```py
Ñ     # All divisors
Ås    # Middle elements
```

Comment: I just got the idea when I scrolled past your answer. Clever answer though.

Comment: The output should have two integers, but as you can see [here](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MTDrcX//xuamAAA "05AB1E – Try It Online"), there is only one integer in case of input which is a `power of 2`.

Comment: @JubayerAbdullahJoy The OP mentioned that if the two numbers are the same, it is OK to output just one (see the comments).

Comment: oh, ok then. I must say your solution is very elegant :)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES7), 35 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,d=n**.5)=>n%d?f(n,-~d):[d,n/d]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjTyfFNk9LS89U09YuTzXFPg0ooluXomkVnaKTp58S@z85P684PydVLyc/XSNNw9DYTFOTC03MxARDzNwIQ8jEEFOnhaWm5n8A)

#### How?

If \$n\$ is a square, \$d=\sqrt{n}\$ is an integer which obviously divides \$n\$, so we immediately have an answer. Otherwise, the first `-~d` will act as \$\lceil{d}\rceil\$ and the next ones as \$d+1\$. Either way, we stop as soon as \$n\equiv 0\pmod{d}\$ which in the worst case (i.e. if \$n\$ is prime) happens when \$d=n\$.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 45 bytes

```python
i=n=input()
while(i*i>n)+n%i:i-=1
print n/i,i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctbCoAgEAXQ/1mFCEFPYkp6gW0mhC7EJGFUqzfq@3D8E9Zdmnit2Jziyd1u0VpHWLEQf4Y0o99S5JglKyTBhMoy@QMSlNQoEb/BbUdsDPUNGSYexhc)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ÆDżṚ$SÞḢ
```

A monadic Link accepting a positive integer which yields a list of two positive integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9qZWxsef//w4ZExbzhuZokU8Oe4bii////MTM2)**

#### How?

```
ÆDżṚ$SÞḢ - Link: positive integer, X   e.g. 12
ÆD       - divisors of X                    [1,2,3,4,6,12]
    $    - last two links as a monad:
   Ṛ     -   reverse                        [12,6,4,3,2,1]
  ż      -   zip                            [[1,12],[2,6],[3,4],[4,3],[6,2],[12,1]]
      Þ  - sort by:
     S   -   sum                            [[3,4],[4,3],[2,6],[6,2],[1,12],[12,1]]
       Ḣ - head                             [3,4]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
Z\J2/)Gy/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PyrGy0hf071S//9/Q2MzAA)

#### Explanation

```
Z\   % Implicit input. Array of divisors
J2/  % Push imaginary unit, divide by 2: gives 0.5j
)    % Index into the array. When used as an index, the imaginary unit means "end".
     % Thus the index 0.5j for [1 2 3 6] would give the 2nd entry (end=4th entry,
     % end/2 = 2nd entry, indexing is 1-based), whereas for [1 2 3 6 12] it would
     % give the "2.5-th" entry. This index is rounded up, so the result would be
     % the 3rd entry
G    % Push input again
y    % Duplicate second-top element in stack (that is, the selected entry)
/    % Divide
     % Implicitly display stack contents
```

Comment: @Downvoter Any suggestion to improve my annswer?

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 51 bytes

```c
i;f(a,c)int*a;{for(i=0;i*i++<c;)c%i||(*a=i);c/=*a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYtBCsIwEEX3nkIClZk0otVQlTE3cZOOJMzCKKW7tGePqRs3/8Hjfd5H5lKEAnjDKGnSnnJ4jyDuSKKlbe9MyI3MM2jvBIkPrjZLiZDMgPkz1lMA1Ty3ygTYDSYh0t8@kqoZLZuXlwSYI3TnHqnC2hWX07q2@6nrrZblCw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,v=1:[n/v,v]*(n/v-v<1>n%v)or f(n,v+1)
```

A recursive function.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIU@nzNbQKjpPv0ynLFZLA0jrltkY2uWplmnmFymkaQDltQ01/6cBOSWpxSUKmXkKGoY6CobGZkDCxERHwdxIR8EEJGJhqWnFpQAEBUWZeSVg1ToK6rp26jpAY0A8zf8A)**

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔⊕⌈Φ₂θ¬﹪θ⊕ιηＩ⟦÷θηη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYy9CsIwFEZ3nyLjDcRBBJdOoggdWkRHcYjJxV7IT5veFN8@pk5@y1nO@cygk4naldKGMXOf/QsTTLLZHOeZ3gHaYBJ6DIwWOv0hnz1cyHG17lPWCW8xcg2U6Cu7aLOLMCnx35H8TYmh/l4TBYaTnhkebeAzLWRxLYZVeErZlLLbH8p2cV8) Link is to verbose version of code. Technically only works up to `a=2⁵³`, but would be stupidly slow well before then anyway. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `c`.

```
≔⊕⌈Φ₂θ¬﹪θ⊕ιη
```

List all of the factors of `c` that do not exceed its floating-point square root, and take the largest `b`.

```
Ｉ⟦÷θηη
```

Calculate and output `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](https://julialang) 54 bytes

### [Try it](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPiflmb7P0/XLik1PTNPIdM2LTMvJS2zqLhEo0LXriLOyM42T00tT7XC1tZAx9AqT9M6Uyfv8PZM69S8lP8OxRn55QppaRqGJiaa/wE)

```
n->begin i=findfirst(x->x^2>=n&&n%x==0,1:n);i,n÷i;end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>52</s> 48 bytes

```python
f=lambda c,i=1:i*i>=c>c%i<1and(i,c/i)or f(c,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VczBCoMwEATQe79ioQhGA7JpUCPGf4kR6UIbRbz49XH1oHiYwzyGmbf1OwUV42h/7t8PDrwkiw1l1Fnf@YRadGFISfqCxLTAmPIgRxHnhcLKFT@lgDdgJQHq16Van6ok59JKCWAF89hqPFUjK94PtTke1KEm7g)

Simply increments `i` until it satisfies

```python
i*i>=c and c%i==0
```

Then returns the pair `(i, c/i)`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 34 bytes

```
.+
$*
(?<-2>(^(1)+?|\1))+$
$.1 $#1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLS8PeRtfITiNOw1BT274mxlBTU1uFS0XPUEFF2fD/f0NjMy5DExMucyMuE0MuQwtLAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert `c` to unary.

```
(?<-2>(^(1)+?|\1))+$
```

The `(1)+` matches a minimal substring `a` of `1`s individually into the `\2` stack, where they are popped off as the entire substring `\1` is repeatedly matched `b` times until it reaches `c`. This popping mechanism thus prevents `b` from exceeding `a`, but as `a` is minimal it must therefore be the smallest factor not less than the square root. Excitingly, .NET allows you to populate the `\2` stack on the first iteration of the `(?<-2>)` loop. (On the remainder of the loops, the `^` no longer matches, so the `\1` alternative is used.)

```
$.1 $#1
```

Output `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 68 bytes

```erlang
f(X)->Y=lists:max([I||I<-lists:seq(1,X),X rem I==0,I*I=<X]),[Y,X/Y].
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcixCsMgEADQPV/heFfOtIFMIWb3DxRxkGLKQUxTFdoh/24LfeOLeQv7Q8Zyz3zU1rUVDMrFqo1LLVMKH3D6PPUs/1HiCwYySEbkmIRW6kb6otVsPJKzZK7W9y0F3sF5FHLpxA8/p3fmGmGFYRwR@/YF)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 52 bytes

```java
n->{int i=n;for(;i*i>n|n%i>0;)i--;return n/i+","+i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/PTsMwDMbvewqrUqV0WwOFin9hPSJxQBx2RBxCl04emVslbqVp7Dl4IB4spGNCcLAs27/v@@SNHnS@Wb0H3HatY9jEWfaMVjY91Ywtyama1FZ7D08aCfYTgK5/s1iDZ82xDS2uYBtvYskOaf3yCtqtfXZEAR6JH05W9z9ABQ0sAuXVHokBF6Sa1gmFU6zog1KszlWGea6c4d4R0BnOknkyQ3UI6mgZcRCDdsDG892/NIBxT7AYc83aODlo25vnRoxspv5AzvjeciQbqbvO7gRl0pnO6tqImDeHBL4@IfnVLHeezVa2PcsuvsGNSNJVlKc@pUjT/OR4EhwmYx1CKC6vQlGW4foilEUobm6/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 39 bytes

```
[d_3R/fq]sE?ddvd[_3R%0=E1-rd3RdlFx]dsFx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/z86Jd44SD@tMLbY1T4lpSwlGshVNbB1NdQtSjEOSslxq4hNKXar@P/f0MISAA)

Or [verify the test cases](https://tio.run/##RY5NC4JAEIbv8yuGpY5mm9IXVieFToJXkVidNQVTW7X895va12Vgnvd9holFk@lEtHisVXVV4oaOw1zfYzqkixWY6T1q3BPRg8JhnS8PLjcUWQEVXh9R4/V6KAM8s7yQqKQgzMu6awGRqmEgyiSr8DyyPc6@2Qf7XTvyCVCCRooL8/@Gg@wtsJ8xnS2l5tYauG3DZgU2B77dwQs).

---

**How it works:**

```
Command  Stack (top on the right)

[        # Macro starts with stack at:
               # n d
               # Prints n/d and d, and then quits.
 d       # n d d
 _3R     # d n d
 /       # d n/d
 f       # Prints stack.
 q       # Quit this macro and the macro which called it.
]sE      # End macro and save it in register E.

?        # n  (Input values and push it on stack.)
dd       # n n n
v        # n n d
         #         d is a potential divisor of n;
         #         it's initialized to int(sqrt(n)).
d        # n n d d
[        # Start macro to be used as a loop.
 _3R     # n d n d
 %       # n d n%d
 0=E     # n d     If d divides n, call macro E to end.
 1-      # n d     New d = d - 1.
 r       # d n
 d       # d n n
 3R      # n n d
 d       # n n d d
         #         The stack is now set up correctly to
         #         go back to the top of the loop, with
         #         d now one step lower.
 lFx     # Call macro F to go back to the top of the loop.
]dsFx    # End macro, save it as F, and execute it.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>48</s> <s>46</s> <s>45</s> 41 bytes

```r
x=scan();b=1:x;a=b[!x%%b&b^2>=x][1];a;x/a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2ODkxT0PTOsnW0KrCOtE2KVqxQlU1SS0pzsjOtiI22jDWOtG6Qj/xv6GxGRfXfwA)

Finds first (`[1]`) divisor (`which(!x%%b)`) that is equal-to or greater than square-root (`b^2>=x`); returns this & reciprocal (`a;x/a`).
[Previous approach (46 bytes)](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2ODkxT0PTOtG2PCMzOUMj00ZXsUJV1dCqQjO6uDRXI1PfSFPbMNY60bpCP/G/obEZF9d/AA) found divisor closest to centre of list-of-divisors, but couldn't be golfed-down so effectively.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pa`, 37 bytes

```perl
$_=0|sqrt;$_--while"@F"%$_;say"@F"/$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tagpriwqMRaJV5XtzwjMydVycFNSVUl3ro4sRLE1FeJ///f0MTkX35BSWZ@XvF/XV9TPQNDg/@6BTmJAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <strike>73</strike> <strike>60</strike> 59 bytes

Not the shortest or best solution by any means, but I think it's a creative approach. Prints the two factors without separator between them and only (consistently) works for inputs up to 1008.

```
r=range(1000)
f=[a*b*(a*a>=a*b)for a in r for b in r].index
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/BbsIwEETv@xUrcbEDRDFELSCl39B71YMjbGoVryPjSOnXu@sEOHN7s7OanR3@0k@gfc6xi5ouRqimaSTY7ktXfSV0pT86JmlDRI2OMGLBfsbv2tHZTHmIjpKwQu3fpISHOh4axRJW@Fkm6PXk/OiRRt@biLdxGEJM5swLrjY1LqfX4u4HixRoy2ne3FDbxLOl3BU7fKkeFJ5mfv62mUNKzgnQWbYppLJyZY1L92mrJIs@Gv2b@SlQbQvvO2gVqMMx/wM)

## Python 3, 57 bytes

Still not the shortest solution, but it's at least somewhat expressive and clear what's going on.

```
lambda n:max((x,n/x)for x in range(1,n+1)if n%x<(x*x<=n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nck9DoMwDEDh3afwUslukYpLVH4EN@mSqg1EKgZFDOb0KQvj@966b9OiVQ7DK//8/P541G72RmSF3o3DktAwKiav45ek0JtwDKgX68mu1g/KnNcUdaNAUj2Z4ay2KeWYB4I4B/UDnIA0bf4D)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
fsIJcQTs@Q2J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P63Y0ys5MKTYIdDI6/9/Q2MzAA)

- `s@Q2` Starting from the floor of the square root of the input:

  - `f` find the first integer \$T\$ such that:
  - `sIcQT` \$T\$ divides the input
- `cQT` gives the input divided by \$T\$ (ie. the other divisor) so we assign that value to `J`
- The two divisors `T` and `J` are then implicitly printed

Comment: 13 bytes, different approach: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyPRzcU53ilNUTUwJPj/f0MLSwA "Pyth – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 66 bytes

```python
def g(s):x=[[a,s/a]for a in range(1,s)if s%a==0];print x[len(x)/2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAr@wl2IWgLOhQ@BLxsJCaEJuogb3eZtJXr0eW3k/nIWChvWljeCwTW/9kYIgCmSU4VGOh6KEMrPVsj5SjVGjmdoKNpsX2gFHSW5Goq3X7AQ)

Comment: I think it needs to work for `1`, right? Also `s%a==0` -> `s%a<1`

Comment: It's usually accepted that a person providing the challenge does not answer their own challenge for a few days, letting other people trying to solve the challenge in the most available languages.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I fail to see how this stops people from posting their own answers. I've been outgolfed on this anyways even before I posted this

Answer (score 0):

## [SageMath](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/index.html), <sup><s>63</s></sup> 60 bytes

```
def f(n):
 d=divisors(n)
 while len(d)>2:d=d[1:-1]
 return d
```

[Try it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwVjMEKwjAQBe_5ikdPCWwPW0PVgP0R8ZYsLpRUtlUPpf9unNswMLkIxNeQHPIt60fXxdbmDt-nzgVzqT6HaUit3jn1_HCwsr2tIjtZDAqt8HwaiWOk80CRiS9X4vH_bLxM6-al2_VAP2EXr-Howg9i9SG5&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 7 bytes

```
─h½§_@/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RlIaMQ3sPLY930P8f@9/Q2IzL0MSEy9yIy8SQy9DC8j8A)

### Explanation

```
─          get a list of all divisors
 h½§       get the divisor at the middlemost index
           (if length is equal returns the smallest of the two middle elements)
    _      duplicate TOS
     @     rrot3 (pops input again and places it as the second item from the top)
      /    divides the input number by the extracted divisor, giving the other divisor
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>108 bytes</strike> 103 bytes

```cpp
#import<iostream>
int n,a,b,i;main(){for(std::cin>>n;i*i++<=n;)n%i<1?a=i,b=n/i:0;std::cout<<a<<' '<<b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpNDsIgEAbQvadoYpq2FqONSRcw4FkAf/ItGAgdV41nx4Vv/WIp53eMrR2RSq5CyJvUp0/uAJaOlVdBwSQPHqf9leu4yUPrCHaODU6YZ7JsJu5By91bqGD5An01/5c/QuSJhm4gCubb2nJbfw)

`Thanks to callingcat, for -5  bytes`

Comment: Thank you, updated :)

Comment: Suggest `b=n%i?b:n/(a=i)` instead of `n%i<1?a=i,b=n/i:0`